# get current month in spanish language Python

Tags: python, django, date, format

Hi i am using a variable `in my template file which gives me a current month value in english

> {{currentMonth}}

how can i convert this into spanish language

Comment: Hava you turned USE_10n on and load l10n in templates?

Comment: Hi i am new to python and i dont know much about this can you please suggest where should i turn this on and how to load this in template file

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a `date` passed to your template from the view. Then to get the current month you need to do

```
{{ mydate|date:"F" }}
```

This will give you the month name i.e January using [template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

To get it in Spanish, enable Spanish by [enabling internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) and creating localization strings for Spanish. You can even use the `humanize` template tag which has [localizations](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/django.po) available in Spanin